# Displaying data inside an array inside an object with React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, loops

I have some data in a separate JS file called `data.js`

```
export default [
      {
        info: [
          {
            cardOne: [
              {
                division: "Company Division",
                infotext: "Some Text",
                cta: "Story Information",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            cardTwo: [
              {
                division: "Rec Division",
                infotext: "Some Text",
                cta: "Story Information",
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            cardThree: [
              {
                division: "Professional Division",
                infotext: "Some Text",
                cta: "Story Information",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
```

In a component I want to display the division of `cardOne`.

Is there a way to access and display just the division of CardOne and display that?

Comment: I would assume you want to display a list of cards, which will require you to loop over your data, which based on your structure you need the following: data[0].info.map((entry) => { ... }). In case you don't want to display a list but just the CardOne as you mentioned, you would just access it directly by doing the following data[0].info[0].cardOne[0].division

Comment: you can use `data[0]['info'][0]['cardOne']`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by calling .map on just the cardOne array in your data.

```
const data = 'location of your exported data';

data['info'][0]['cardOne'].map((card) => (
   JSX here
))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the division of cardOne you can access it like this:

```
import * as data from "./data"

<h1>{data.default[0].info[0].cardOne[0].division}</h1>
```